# Automapper: Hierarchical intermediate object issue

Tags: c#, automapper, hierarchy

I've inherited a project that has a rather novel class structure which I need to manipulate for a 3rd party webservice.

Basically, the source object has a structure of `parent->collection->collection member object` (i.e. the collection member has simple properties plus a class member object - the example should explain it better). The Dto is simpler and is just `parent->collection`.

The issue lies with the fact that the `TrackInfoDto` object (these form the collection members in the Dto) **must** take properties from the `TrackDefinition.TrackType` object. This is an object that belongs to the source `parent.collection`.

I've tried so many ways to map this relationship in AutoMapper and have drawn a blank.

My main question is:

- How can I map the source structure to the destination structure, given that the source object and target object have an intermediate object to navigate.

To assist, below is a code example of what I've tried so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;

namespace AutoMapperTest
{
    /*
     *  requires Automapper  PM>
     *  Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 3.0.0
    */

    /* source class objects */
    public class Track
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FileId { get; set; }
        public string MediaName { get; set; }

        public List<TrackDefinition> TrackDefinitions { get; set; }

        public Track()
        {
            TrackDefinitions = new List<TrackDefinition>();
        }
    }

    public class TrackDefinition
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string TrackTypeName { get; set; }
        public TrackType TrackType { get; set; }

        public TrackDefinition()
        {
            TrackType = new TrackType();
        }
    }

    public class TrackType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FileTag { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    /* destination mapped object model */
    public class TrackDto
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string MediaName { get; set; }
        public string FileId { get; set; }

        public List<TrackInfoDto> TrackInfo { get; set; }

        public TrackDto()
        {
            TrackInfo = new List<TrackInfoDto>();
        }
    }

    public class TrackInfoDto
    {
        public string FileTag { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region setup
            // create small test bed of source data
            var sourceTracks = new List<Track>();
            // add a few tracks (index start 1 loops)
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var newTrack = new Track
                {
                    Id = string.Format("{0}", i),
                    MediaName = string.Format("media track {0}", i),
                    FileId = string.Format("file reference {0}", i)
                };
                for (int j = 1; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    var trackDefinition = new TrackDefinition
                    {
                        Id = string.Format("TD Id {0}", i),
                        TrackTypeName = "a track type",
                        TrackType =
                        {
                            Id = j*i,
                            FileTag = string.Format("file tag {0}", j*i),
                            Name = string.Format("name # {0}", j*i)
                        }
                    };
                    newTrack.TrackDefinitions.Add(trackDefinition);
                }
                sourceTracks.Add(newTrack);
            }
            #endregion

            #region map
            // now for the problem - how to map the fact that the hierarchy
            // in Track->TrackDefinition->TrackType
            // needs to *miss out* the middle object (TrackDefinition) when
            // we map down to the Dto's
            Mapper.CreateMap<Track, TrackDto>()
                .ForMember(x => x.TrackInfo, opt => opt.Ignore());
            Mapper.CreateMap<TrackDefinition, TrackInfoDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FileTag, func => func.MapFrom(src => src.TrackType.FileTag));
            Mapper.CreateMap<TrackDefinition, TrackInfoDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, func => func.MapFrom(src => src.TrackType.Name));
            // first thing -make sure no mapping issues
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            // i've even tried to see if that would coerce - nope!!
            //Mapper.CreateMap<TrackType, TrackInfoDto>();

            // map our source objects down to our dtos
            var trackDtos = Mapper.Map<ICollection<Track>, ICollection<TrackDto>>(sourceTracks);

            // by inspecting the trackDtos members, we SHOULD see the TrackInfoDto as being
            // populated, but alas not. This is the missing puzzle piece
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Hope the code isn't too difficult to understand, I've simplified it a lot from the real life scenario, but kept the crucial caveats in place.

Comment: not enough. It isn't really clear what you're asking still. Its just a code example and a load of waffle.

Comment: Have you looked at using `BeforeMap`? I don't have time to look at this now but you could use `BeforeMap` and, within the anonymous function declaration, explicitly call `Mapper.Map` on the member you're struggling to map conventionally

Comment: levelnis - thanks for understanding immediately my issue and offering a good suggestion. i'll take a look at that. thanks again

Comment: dave - I've edited my question. if it were an easy one, i'd def have solved it rather than asking. anyway - thanks for the constructive advice tho :-)

Comment: Can you please restrict your post to a single answerable question? Posting sample code and stating aims doesn't help us help you (nor make this question useful for the next 100 people coming from Google) :-) Thanks!

Comment: sklivvz - taken your advice and qualified the purpose of the question. hope this helps.

Comment: btw -to all, this has been quite a constructive little Q&A comments session as it really (again) highlighted the fact that often what's on your mind is *not* always on the page and also, that with complex questions, less is definitely more. I truly have learned more in framing this question (incorrectly), than I have in any previous SO posts that I have made or answered. thanks again, now let's hope for a perfect answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've Solved it, I was looking at the wrong approach to map the intermediate object, i just needed to `ResolveUsing()` it. Here's the one single change:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Track, TrackDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TrackInfo, func => func
        .ResolveUsing(src => src.TrackDefinitions));
```